# Install R packages from Windows CMD

Tags: windows, r, cmd

I'm trying to install two R packages from the Windows CMD. I've looked around and I can't find a completely automatic way of achieving this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075709/install-binary-zipped-r-package-via-command-line

Your question seems to be duplicate with this earlier question, though this one doesn't address automation.

Comment: I've tried R CMD INSTALL -l C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\library reshape and it doesn't work it tells me no such package exists. I've googled this quite a bit and checked stackoverflow before posting, none of the solutions offered seem to work for me. :(

Comment: Interesting. Are you absolutely sure that the path to the file is inputted correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me it works using rscript.exe. Similar to [Install binary zipped R package via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075709/install-binary-zipped-r-package-via-command-line), but that one is for a local file.

Example of getting 'igraph' package:

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin>RScript.exe  -e "install.packages('igraph', repos
='https://cran.rstudio.com/')"
```

Parameter `repos` has to be provided, otherwise you get *error*

```
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") :
trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: install.packages -> contrib.url
Execution halted
```

To pick a mirror you like, visit https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html

Answer (score -1):

Use this command on Windows PowerShell

```
winget install -e --id Microsoft.ROpen
```

https://winget.run/search?query=r